# Why is this readFile operation in Node throwing an error?

Tags: node.js

I have this code using socket.io on a Node server:

```
io.sockets.on(
   'connection'
   ,function (socket) {
    reader = require('fs');
    fileContents = reader.readFile(__dirname + '/textCharacters.txt'
                                   ,'utf8'
                                   ,function(data, err) {
                                              if (err) throw err;
                                              console.log(data);
                                    }
                           );
    socket.emit('retrievedFileContent', {content:fileContents} );
    }
);
```

When I check the Node server debug, the error shows the contents of the file, so I know the file is being read, but why isn't it being returned to the `fileContents` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [`readFile(filename, encoding, callback)` function](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback) doesn't *return* the file contents, *it passes them* as the second argument to the given callback function.  Try modifying your code as such:

```javascript
var fs = require('fs');

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var filename = __dirname + '/textCharacters.txt';
  fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    socket.emit('retrievedFileContent', {content:data});
  });
});
```